# Query in sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 3 tables:

- TABLE company(_id, name);
- TABLE employee(_id, name, idCompany);
- TABLE task (_id, name, idCompany, idEmployee);

I need a query that returns all the taks stored in my DB and show the name of the company, employee. I mean, I need to return something like this:

TABLE RESULT(_id, name, idCompany, idEmployee, nameCompany, nameEmployee)

The attributes idEmployee and idCompany can be null.

Note: I'm using sqlite3, so I can only use LEFT JOIN and INNER JOIN.

Comment: I dont want to influence the answer because maybe is there a better way to do it.

Comment: How can you get nameCompany, nameEmployee when they are not in any of the databases?

Comment: @kiduxa that is not how this site works, show what you have if you want help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure of how limited sqlite3 is, but this might get you started:

```
SELECT task._id, task.name, task.idCompany, task.idEmployee, 
    company.name as nameCompany, employee.name as nameEmployee
FROM task
LEFT JOIN company ON task.idCompany = company._id
LEFT JOIN employee ON task.idEmployee = employee._id
```